# Error occurs when I open xsd schema in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xsd

When I try to open XSD schema in my Visual Studio 2008 raises error like this:
"An unexpected error occurred in the .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5"
I don't use Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 and connection strings for SQL Server 2005 are stored in XSD table adapters.

Any ideas ?

Comment: why cant you open it in notepad??

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the file and select "Open With..." to see the "application" that is associated with the file type. It seems that you have it set to use some SQL-related viewer instead of the default "XML Editor."